# generating lists of integers with constraint

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning, programming

Suppose you have the list $a=(k_1,k_2,k_3, \dots, k_N)$ such that $k_{i}\; (i=1,\ldots, N)$ are non negative integers. How can you get all the lists that satisfy the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{N} k_{i}=M$?

Comment: Take a look at `IntegerPartitions`.

Comment: ...or `FrobeniusSolve[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [`FrobeniusSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html) like so:

```
ClearAll[solutions]
byFrobenius[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] :=
  FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, n], m];
```

This works like so:

```
byFrobenius[5, 3]
(* {{0, 0, 5}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 2, 3}, 
    {0, 3, 2}, {0, 4, 1}, {0, 5, 0}, 
    {1, 0, 4}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 2}, 
    {1, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 0}, {2, 0, 3}, 
    {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 0}, 
    {3, 0, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 0}, 
    {4, 0, 1}, {4, 1, 0}, {5, 0, 0}} *)
```

Let's compare this to a brute force solution:

```
ClearAll[byBruteForce];
byBruteForce[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] :=
  With[{candidates = Tuples[Range[0, m], n]},
   Select[candidates, Total /* EqualTo[m]]];
ContainsExactly[byBruteForce[5, 3], byFrobenius[5, 3]]
(* True *)
```

Performance of `byFrobenius` is, of course, much better:

```
byBruteForce[10, 6]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.64395, Null} *)

byFrobenius[10, 6]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0364338, Null} *)
```

We can get even faster by using [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html), as suggested by @geom, but remember to use the second argument to ensure we don't get lists that are too long (which will then be truncated by `PadRight`).

```
byIntegerPartitions[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] := 
 Catenate[Permutations /@ 
   PadRight[IntegerPartitions[m, n], {Automatic, n}]]
```

This is fast and correct:

```
byIntegerPartitions[10, 6]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0007277, Null} *)

ContainsExactly[byIntegerPartitions[10, 6], byFrobenius[10, 6]]
(* True *)
```

Interestingly, if we do some [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), a hand-written, recursive solution can beat `byFrobenius` for performance (though it's still much slower than `byIntegerPartitions`):

```
byRecursion[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] :=
  Module[{memo},
   memo[k_, 1] := {{k}};
   memo[0, l_] := {ConstantArray[0, l]};
   memo[k_, l_] := memo[k, l] =
     Catenate[Map[Map[Prepend[#], memo[k - #, l - 1]] &, Range[0, k]]];
   
   memo[m, n]];

byRecursion[10, 6]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0172348, Null} *)

ContainsExactly[byRecursion[10, 6], byFrobenius[10, 6]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is:

```
f[m_,n_]:=Flatten[Permutations /@ PadRight[IntegerPartitions[m], {Automatic, n}], 1]
```

e.g

```
f[2, 4]
(*=> {{2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, 
{1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}} *)
```

An answer with `FrobeniusSolve[]` as suggested by @J.M.'s ennui, or any improvements in my answer would be appreciated

**EDIT**
After @Pillsy's comment my answer should be modified as:

```
f[m_,n_]:=Catenate[Permutations /@ PadRight[IntegerPartitions[m,n], {Automatic, n}]]
```

Comment: This contains results that don't satisfy the constraints. `Length@Select[f[10, 6], Total /* UnequalTo[10]]` gives 84.

Comment: @Pillsy True! I missed it. I modified my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
f1[n_, m_] := IntegerPartitions[m, {n}, Range[m, 0, -1]]
f2[n_, m_] := 
 FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, n], m] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]
```

(Please notice that $N$ is before $M$) :P

#### Validation

```
f1[6, 10] // RepeatedTiming
f2[6, 10] // RepeatedTiming
%[[2]] === %%[[2]]
```

> ```
> {8.628*10^-6, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
>    2, 8}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 
>    5}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 8}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 7}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 6}, {0,
>     0, 0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 
>    2, 4, 4}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 7}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 
>    6}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 5}, {0,
>     0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3}, {0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4}, {0, 0, 2, 
>    2, 3, 3}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
>    4}, {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {0,
>     2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 1, 1, 
>    1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}}}
>
> {0.0093, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
>    8}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5}, {0,
>     0, 0, 1, 1, 8}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 7}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 
>    1, 4, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 
>    4}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 7}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 6}, {0,
>     0, 1, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 5}, {0, 0, 1, 
>    2, 3, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3}, {0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4}, {0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 
>    3}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4}, {0,
>     1, 1, 2, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 2, 
>    2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
>    3}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}}}
>
> True
> ```

So the method based on `IntegerPartitions` is significantly faster. In order to get complete results:

```
f1[6, 10] // Map[Permutations] // Apply[Join]; // 
  RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00017, Null}
> ```

```
f1[4, 2] // Map[Permutations] // Apply[Join] //
  RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000012, {{0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 
>    0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 
>    1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}}}
> ```

Comment: Both `f1[2,4]` and `f2[2,4]` give `{{0, 4}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}}` but the correct answer is `{{2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}}`

Comment: @geom Oh, I put $N$ in front, so you should use `f1[4, 2]`. If you want to get complete results, try `f1[4, 2] // Map[Permutations /* Reverse] // Flatten[#, 1] &` :)

Comment: I see, it would be helpful if you could modify your answer (for future readers :) )

Comment: @geom You're right. I've updated!